# how to setup eclim with android developer tool (eclipse 4.2)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclim

I have the Android Developer Tool which shows eclipse version 4.2 (juno).
According to Eclim site required version of Eclim is as

> Eclipse 4.3.x (Kepler) (Eclim 2.2.x), Eclipse 3.7.x (Indigo) (Eclim 1.7.x), or Eclipse 3.8 (Eclim 1.7.13 or greater)

I thought eclim 1.7.18 will work with eclipse 4.2. I also tried 2.3 but none are compatible with eclipse 4.2 which comes bundled in ADT.
So which version of Eclim should I use?

Comment: Try to write to eclim mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/eclim-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got ADT bundle with eclipse 4.2 and installed eclim 2.2.6 which doesn't complain about eclipse's version.

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

For other readers not satisfied I'll tell my story, before you read you must know I'm that type of developers who love using the CLI and thinks that keyboard shurtcuts are faster than using a mouse, if you don't agree may be this setup is not for you:

### Install main tools

- I've downloaded Eclipse Luna (4.4.0) from the eclipse project website.
- Download the Android SDK.
- Later install the ADT Plugin (through *Help > Install New Software*).
- After installing the ADT Plugin will ask for the path to the Android SDK.
- Later on installed Eclim (2.4.0), it will ask for the eclipse installation folder as well for the *.vim* folder.
- Start the Eclim daemon service. (In debian you can use *update-rc.d* to make it always run, or search a solution for your system, you can setup to start at system start, let the ideas come out!)

### Setting up the Android Development Vim Studio

- Check Eclim is up by typing in vim `:PingEclim` you should see the version of Eclim as well of Eclipse.
- I suggest installing the *NeoComplCache* Vim plugin it integrates nicely with Eclim autocomplete, in the [Eclim doc web site  it says what you need to add to integrate it](http://eclim.org/vim/code_completion.html).
- Eclim will detect the android-sdk path based on the setup you made on eclipse but if not you can define the android-sdk path ([see Eclim docs](http://eclim.org/vim/java/android.html)).

### How to create projects and install on device

- With my NERDTreee I automagically CD in the selected root dir and use `:ProjectCreate %/MyProjectFolder -n android`, it will ask for some configs.
- Later in order to you can build and install the app to your phone you need first to generate the build files (eclipse doesn't share these build files), use `:!android project update --path %/MyProjectFolder` (note you can omit '*/MyProjectFolder*' if you're already inside that folder). You can add `--target` and `--name` flags if you want to update these values.
- At this point you can work in your project without any issues, code completion works excellent, if you need import something use `:JavaImport` but you know you can map it.
- Wenever you want to test the app in your device (I use a physical device) use `:Ant debug install` and if build succeeds use `:!adb shell am start -n your.package.name/.YourMainActivity` this will fire the app in your device just like eclipse does.

You can combine the build and install command with `:!ant debug install && adb shell am start -n your.package.name/.YourMainActivity`. Also remember to keep a terminal open for your logcat `adb logcat` or if you declare a tag (I suggest doing it) `adb logcat -s "MyTag"`

### Why to use eclim?

I was in a pain after updating my eclipse juno only errors was shown, I was tired of downloading, installing, updating eclipse, even the bundled ADT was bugy, Android Studio looks very ugly on linux by the swing font rendering, many hours were wasted at the end I just search for integrate my vim (I use it for web dev) and never looked back, used Eclim because I had the buggied eclipse on my system (is still here can't use that slow bugy crap, I HATE ECLIPSE).

### Does it worth it?

If you don't have eclipse I suggest you try another Android Development Vim Studio without eclim, but if you already have Eclipse, go for eclim. And yes I'm happier to code this way in Vim rather than in eclipse, the only miss is the GUI Layout Designer. As some people say *If you want something done well, better do it your self*

### Looks like a lot of work

Yes, for sure I'll start building a vimscript for this.

Comment: Thanks for your easy to follow answer. But is it possible to use it with gradle. Can you help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895263/how-to-use-eclim-with-gradle-project