# How to use eclim with gradle project

Tags: eclipse, vim, gradle, eclim

My eclim setup working perfectly with eclipse project. But I want to use gradle build system.
I am working with Libgdx framework and it provide gradle templete project. 
So is there any way to use eclime + eclipse + gradle

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to check out the [Eclipse Gradle plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html), although in short you can add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to your project and then run `gradle eclipse` from your terminal in the root folder of your project. That should generate the necessary files for Eclipse to recognize your project, although you might need to edit the [.classpath](http://eclim.org/vim/java/classpath.html) file for proper autocompletions.

That will get Eclim to recognize your project with :ProjectOpen and proper autocompletion and other goodness.

The bad is that Gradle tasks and changes to your build.gradle will require manual changes to the Eclipse side of things.

Edit: There's a new plugin available for this purpose that replaces eclim for gradle projects (but is android oriented) called [Vim-Grand](https://github.com/meonlol/vim-grand). It's pre-alpha and you'll want the refactor branch for now, but it's working well enough for me

Comment: But where are routes for classpaths?

Answer (score 2):

You should combine it with [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

What I did was use the gdx-setup.jar to create my project. I then imported it into eclipse like a normal gradle project. I closed eclipse and started up elcimd. Put "let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'" in my .vimrc file. Followed the elcim instructions to use :CreateProject and that was it.

This guide was really helpful: http://www.lucianofiandesio.com/vim-configuration-for-happy-java-coding

Comment: How do you run your android/desktop project from vim. Can you please tell me more, how you use `:CreateProject`. Because it is multi-module project. Did I need to do it with every module.

Comment: I map <leader>g to build from within VIM which basically runs ./gradlew desktop:run. Like this: 

nnoremap <expr> <leader>g system('./gradlew desktop:run')

You can of course map many if you are building android or whatever. The 2 links I provided to YouCompleteMe and lucianofiandesio are very detailed and should suit your needs. I basically have 1 libgdx project with the android/ios/desktop in one folder and run the :CreateProject inside there.

Comment: I got about build command but still confused in :CreateProject. Should I consider all models as a single project and use `:CreateProject` in parent folder. Or I need to do it in all three(android/ios/desktop) modules separately.

Comment: I ran it in the base folder and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @HinesBourne Did yoy manage to get the auto-completation and validation working?

Comment: Yes, Jesus. I followed both YouCompleteMe and http://www.lucianofiandesio.com/vim-configuration-for-happy-java-coding and was able to get it working.

Comment: I've been working on this as well. I am finding I need to import my project and use 'build model' within the Eclipse UI. Once that is done, I can kill eclipse UI and start eclimd, and everything works as expected including :JavaImportOrganize. I'm working now on doing the import and build model from the command line, so I never have to open Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to get most or all Eclim functionality working with my libgdx project this way:

- create a new libgdx project with their tools
- start Eclipse
- Import --> Gradle Project --> Build Model per usual libgdx project creation
- shut off Eclipse, start Eclim

I get organize imports, java validation, autocompletion, all the good stuff.

That said, I want to figure out how to do this all without having to use Eclipse. I think the missing piece is the Build Models functionality. Still researching ...